# Replace a one javascript object with another object

Tags: javascript, reset, javascript-objects

On page load I am creating two Javascript Objects, `objDemo1` and `objDemo1Backup` where the latter is simply an exact copy of the first.

e.g.

```
objDemo1 { 
    sub_1 = { something: 123, somethingElse: 321 },
    sub_2 = { something: 456, somethingElse: 654 }
}
```

I can modify the values in `sub_` as well as add / delete new `sub_`'s but the only object I am editing is `objDemo1`. i.e. I never change `objDemo1Backup`

I have a reset button that when clicked will reset `objDemo1` back to what it was when the page originally loaded (i.e. `objDemo1 = objDemo1Backup`). This is where I am having the issue..

**How do I set `objDemo1` to `objDemo1Backup`?**

I have tried:

```
objDemo1 = objDemo1Backup;
```

and

```
objDemo1 = null;
var objDemo1 = objDemo1Backup;
```

...as well as similar variations but nothing seems to work.
Any ideas?

- Note: I can confirm that at the point of resetting, `objDemo1Backup` is exactly the same as it was when I created it and `objDemo1` has changed.
- My code is definetly hitting the "reset" functionality, where I've tried the `objDemo1 = objDemo1Backup`... I just cannot figure out the syntax to replace the object.

Comment: I'm going to assume that what is happening is that since both `objDemo1` and `objDemo1Backup` point to the same object, when you change one, both are changed. This may not seem intuitive, but it is the way javascript works. Google **"javascript clone object"** for more details.

Comment: You're playing with object reference, not cloning it. You should clone your object instead of assign it using =

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JavaScript objects are passed by reference, never by value. So:

```
var objDemo, objDemoBackup;
objDemo = {
    sub_1: "foo";
};
objDemoBackup = objDemo;
objDemo.sub_2 = "bar";
console.log(objDemoBackup.sub_2);   // "bar"
```

To get a copy, you must use a copy function. JavaScript doesn't have one natively but here is a `clone` implementation: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript)

```
var objDemo, objDemoBackup;
objDemo = {
    sub_1: "foo";
};
objDemoBackup = clone(objDemo);
objDemo.sub_2 = "bar";
console.log(objDemoBackup.sub_2);   // undefined
```

Comment: So if I wanted to reset objDemo back to what objDemoBackup was a point of cloning I would do this: `objDemo = clone(objDemoBackup);`

Comment: Yes, you must clone it again or you'll end with a reference :)

Answer (score 11):

I'm using *angularjs* and it took me some time to find out how to copy an object to another object. Normally you'll get an objects clone by calling *clone* or here in angular *copy*:

```
var targetObj = angular.copy(sourceObj);
```

This gives you a new cloned instance (with a new reference) of the source object. But a quick look into the docs reveals the second parameter of *copy*:

```
angular.copy(sourceObj, targetObj)
```

This way you can override a target object with the fields and methods of the source **and** also keep the target objects reference.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know `angular.copy` could take a target object. Thanks!

Comment: There is no AngularJS tag in this question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
ObjectConstructor.assign(target: T, source: U): T & U
```

It takes up two parameters: `target` and `source`. When function completes, all internals of `target` object will be appended with `source` one.

Comment: Not exactly, it is a merge not replacement.  In the MDN example in your link, the updated target has property "a" and the source does not.  In the OP's example, the properties have the same names so this is not an issue.

Comment: As @AlienTechnology stated Object.assign doest not create a new instance

Comment: Object.assign does not replace the object, it merges with it.